# Model data doesn't show on tableviewrow (Titanium Studio)

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm starting with titanium studio and i've followed the "create your first app" tutorial on the titanium documentation. Here's my code so far:

evento.js (model)

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
        columns: {
            "descricao": "string",
            "realizado": "boolean"
        },
        adapter: {
            type: "sql",
            collection_name: "eventos"
        }
    },
    extendModel: function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection: function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // extended functions and properties go here
        });

        return Collection;
    }
};
```

index.js (controller)

```
var meusEventos = Alloy.Collections.eventos;
var evento = Alloy.createModel('eventos',{
    descricao: 'Principiantes',
    realizado: true
});


meusEventos.add(evento);
evento.save();
meusEventos.fetch();
$.index.open();
```

index.xml (view)

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="eventos"/>
    <Window class="container">
        <TableView dataCollection="eventos">
            <TableViewRow descricao="{descricao}" realizado="{realizado}"></TableViewRow>
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

But when i run the app on my fone it doesn't show any tableviewrows. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Alloy>
<Collection src="eventos"/>
<Window class="container">
    <TableView dataCollection="eventos">
        <TableViewRow descricao="{descricao}" realizado="{realizado}"></TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

it makes a custom property name `descricao` and `realizado`
try to use property `title` in `TableViewRow` like :

```
<TableViewRow title="{descricao}" realizado="{realizado}">
```

hope this will help you.